# Sharing data across SwiftUI app: better pattern to choose?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, swiftui, architecture

I'm working on delivery app, where I should have an access to shop (title, phone), auth (is logged in, user name, email) and cart (add/remove/clear) modules across the app.

For now I'm sharing all the data with EnvironmentObjects, but causes a mess in the code to inject some or all of those three "services" into each and every view (there are a lot of sheets).

Singlton can solve the problem, but AFAIK singleton is an anti-pattern, especially if I have even three singletons in the app. Is there any more efficient way to do this stuff? I use MVVM in the app.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Any good resources about the topic (design patterns) are also more than welcome

Answer (score 1):

Shop and auth information could be stored in `UserDefaults` (do not put any sensitive info like passwords there) and easily accessed in the views. And I would keep cart controller/service as an `EnvironmentObject` (maybe even a `Singleton` if implemented correctly). This way you reduce your 3 dependencies to just one, which should be easier to handle/manage.

And if you are familiar with such patterns/ideas as `Composition Root`, then you could even inject cart object manually into every single view that needs it (much more hassle than `EnvironmentObject`).